# Windows Fails to recognize installed commands while using child_process.exec() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, exec, child-process

I am able to run 'ipconfig.exe' or 'netstat.exe' using exec but I am unable to run .bat command "chef" or "chef-apply".
    **OS: Windows 7**

```
exports.testscript=function(req,res){
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
console.log("inside function");
var child = exec('chef-apply azurepro.rb' , {cwd :'C:\Users\xyz\chef-repo'},
function(error, stdout, stderr){
console.log(stdout); 
console.log(stderr); 
if (error !== null) {
  console.log(error);
  return;
}
    });

//child.stdin.end();
};
```

I am getting this error,

```
{ [Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd.exe',
  path: 'cmd.exe',
 cmd: 'cmd.exe /s /c "chef-apply azurepro.rb"' }
```

From my understanding the bin path for command is not resolved. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've heard of users of my node module that a restart helps :D
Sorry, but I mean that for real. Not joking https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/35#issuecomment-133476657

Comment: But I think this is only true for the case when you recently installed your executable.